# Can we use FirebaseListAdapter to populate TabLayout in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a firebase database similar to the following -

```
"root":
{
    "survey":
    {
        "1":
        {
            "survey_question":"Who is a better player?",
            "options":
            {
                "1":"Ronaldo",
                "2":"Messi"
            }
        },
        "2":
        {
            "survey_question":"Who is a better superhero?",
            "options":
            {
                "1":"Iron man",
                "2":"Captain America"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the surveys in TabLayout such that one question, along with its options, gets displayed on one tab. The number of surveys can be changed dynamically. If there are *n* surveys, then there should be *n* tabs to display them. Each tab has the same layout.

**Note:** The TabLayout is present in a fragment which also contains a ViewPager.

What is the best way to implement this? Should I use FirebaseListAdapter or FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, or any other thing?

**Edit:** I want the surveys to be displayed in the following format -

[image: Display surveys GIF]

Comment: You can easily write your own ViewPagerAdapter. Add a ValueEventListener, and when you get the result save it to a list and refresh

Comment: @Linxy I am not actually getting how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (pseudo-code)

```
public class Survey implements Parcelable {
        //.... firebase model class
    }
```

Adapter

```
public class FirebasePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Survey> surveyList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Fragment> surveyFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    private DatabaseReference surveyReference;

    public FirebasePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        surveyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("root/survey");
        surveyReference.addEventListener(valueEventListener);
        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                surveyList.clear();
                surveyFragments.clear(); // if you implement .equals() in Survey
                // you do a for loop that only updates the changed/added/removed items, instead of all of them..

                for(DataSnapshot surveySnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String surveyNumber = surveySnapshot.getKey();
                    Survey survey = surveySnapshot.getValue(Survey.class);
                    surveyList.add(survey);
                    surveyFragments.add(SurveyFragment.newInstance(surveyNumber, survey));
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error){
                //...
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return surveyFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return surveyFragments.size();
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        if (valueEventListener != null) {
            surveyReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }
    }
}
```

You would implement the SurveyFragment to take in as argument your survey object, (make sure its parcelable or serializeable). 
I think something like this would work in most cases. 
If the surveyList updated its size (add, remove) in real time, then you could probably replace the ValueEventListener with a ChildEventListener but you would have to do a bit more work, ADD, DELETE, MOVE... Check this old version of the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, it has similar functionality which you would need to port to the PagerAdapter.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/version-1.0.0/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java or

https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/matteo/firebase_recycleview/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: What data type should I use for "Options" in Survey model class?

Comment: Your solution worked. Now, what should I do to get responses from radio buttons on pressing the `Continue` button, and shift to next tab?

Comment: You can handle that within SurveyFragment. As it is given a survey object which should contain it's id, you can save the responses to the database as a SurveyResponse to whatever node you want, depending on your structure e.g. `/surveyResponses/userId/randomId/surveyResponseObject = { surveyId = "1" }`

Comment: After it is saved, you can go to the next tab sending a "nextTab" event to your activity.. Depending on your architecture, you can use a LiveData (arch. components) or a Shared ActivityScoped Object(Dagger2) or a BroadcastReceiver (no libraries), or an EventBus (otto), or the easiest would be to just call something like `((MyActivity) getActivity()).goToNextTab();` from your Fragment.  Then that method should just call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1)` make sure you check if you are on the last page (if you are, don't call the method) or you'll get a IndexOutOfBounds

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

You can use this query to get the questions:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("survey");
Query q=ref.orderByChild("survey_question").equalTo(questionhere);
```

more info here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: This is not something I asked for. I want all the surveys to be displayed in different tabs. I am not searching for a particular question. That query line is of no use to me.

Comment: In the question you are only asking what to choose which I answered. The query is a bonus

Comment: if you just want the surveys, then just do a listener and retrieve the questions and options

Comment: I am not getting how to use a listener in this situation.

Comment: valueventlistener to retrieve the questions and answers? Isnt that what you want to retrieve or something else?

Comment: Yes. I want all the surveys to be displayed on different tabs.

Comment: okay then just retrieve the question and the answers with a checkbox next to the answer

Comment: Yes. That's what I need. Please guide me on how to do this.

Comment: I will be doing the whole app then :p Why do you want to retrieve all the questions and answers in each tab though? Also just use a firebaserecycleradapter and retreive a question and its answers in each item

Comment: No, I don't want all the surveys in each tab. I want one survey in one tab. So _n_ surveys in _n_ tabs.

Comment: eh then the best thing to use the query above, you have to use a condition to be able to only retrieve one survey in the each fragment

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426688/android-firebaserecycleradapter-in-fragment

Comment: I can't use the query above because I don't know the _questionhere_ parameter which you passed in the _equalTo()_ function. I just know that there are some questions in the database and I have to display them in different tabs.

Comment: @ChiragMittal check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g1_UH_6VQc. Just create a POJO class and use firebaserecycleradapter to display all the questions and answers in each item